# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ assuming it exists.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ assuming it
>   exists.

Since limit exists, we can approach from any curve to get the limit...

if we approach (0,0) from y=x

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3+x^3}{x^2+x^2} = x = 0$

is this method correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The big question is whether the limit actually exists.

Comment: @Mathematician42 it was given in question it exists, so I can use any path right.. Limit will be same.. so I just need to find limit via one path and that will be the final answer..right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Suppose we would do the same with $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$. Suppose the limit exists, chosing the path $x=y$ yields $\frac{1}{2}$, but chosing the path $y=2x$ yields $\frac{2}{5}$. Both answers are correct assuming the limit exists. In fact anything you answer is correct. So as long as you assume a limit exists you can find the value using any path, but that doesn't mean you necessarily find the same answer as your neighbour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to solve this problem is to use polar coordinates

$$x=r\cos \phi$$
$$y=r\sin \phi$$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^3(\cos^3 \phi+\sin^3 \phi)}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\left[r(\cos^3 \phi+\sin^3 \phi)\right].$$

Because $|\cos^3 \phi + \sin^3\phi|\leq 1$ the limit exists (by the sandwich theorem) and is zero.

**Remark:** If you assume that the limit exists then you could also choose $y=0$ and let $x \to 0$ (because it does not matter how you approach $(0,0)$).

Comment: actually in question it is told that limit exists, so I can choose an easy path right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but as pointed out by all the comments you should rather try to also show that it exists. The way the question is formulated is not the standard formulation. Look also at my remark.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$y=tx$$ then we get
$$\frac{x^3+t^3x^3}{x^2+t^2x^2}=x\frac{1+t^3}{1+t^2}$$ this tends to Zero if $x$ tends to zero

Comment: It does not solve the problem in the comment above "The big question is whether the limit actually exists."

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|<\epsilon.$$
Let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then
$$\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|+\left|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|$$
$$=|x|\underbrace{\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|}_{\leq 1}+|y|\underbrace{\left|\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|}_{\leq 1}$$
$$\leq|x|+|y|\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<2\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
This proves that the limit exists and is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|&=\left|(x+y)\cdot\frac{x^2-xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\
&=|x+y|\left|1-\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\
&\le|x+y|\left(1+\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\right)\quad(\because\text{the triangle inequality})\\
&\le|x+y|\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\quad(\because\text{the AM-GM inequality})\\
&=\frac{3}{2}|x+y|
\end{align}
and $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{3(x+y)}{2}=0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$ by the Squeeze Theorem.